# How can I minified CSS and JS with custom configuration?

Tags: javascript, css, obfuscation, minimization

I need a reliable JS and CSS minimizer which is possible to customize and compatible with modern CSS3 properties. I prefer it has something like property file in order to configuration. 
Would you please help me on this?

Comment: [HTML5 Boilterplate Build script](https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script)

Comment: i'm looking for it. 1+ for this. Thanks @DidierGhys

Comment: What sort of configurations do you need to make?

Answer (score 4):

As @Calgary Coder mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843871/javascript-and-css-minimizer):

> There are a wide variety of options. In terms of actual tools, the
>   most common are:
>
> 1) [Google Closure Compiler Service](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)
>
> 2) [Microsoft AJAX Minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584)
>
> 3) [YuiCompressor](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/) or [YuiCompressor.NET](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/)
>
> and likely many more, but I have used each of these tools, and all are
>   great to work with.
>
> If you are working with a .NET application library, there are also
>   various other options that extend these base tools, to combine like
>   resources and reduce overall HTTP requests.
>
> 1) [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/)
>
> 2) [Xpedite](http://xpedite.codeplex.com/)
>
> 3) [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/05/26/SquishIt-The-Friendly-ASPNET-JavaScript-and-CSS-Squisher.aspx)
>
> Again, also likely many more...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent JS minifier: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Used by jQuery